# How to create a random variable whose parameters are themselves random variables in SymPy?

Tags: python, probability, sympy

I have a random variable Y whose distribution is Poisson with parameter that is itself a random variable X, which is Poisson with parameter 10.

How can I use SymPy to automatically calculate the covariance between X and Y? 
The code

```
from sympy.stats import *
x1 = Poisson("x1", 3)
x2 = Poisson("x2", x1)
print(covariance(x2,x1))
```

raises an error
`ValueError: Lambda must be positive`

The documentation is not clear to me on this matter, and playing around with the function `given` did not seem to work.

Comment: The positivity requirement has been removed in the latest SymPy version (1.1). However, handling multivariate random variables like that is not yet supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of manipulation is not implemented in SymPy. But you can pass a symbol (z1 below) for the parameter of a distribution. Then after the first step of computation, replace z1 by x1 and take expected value.

```
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.stats import Poisson, E
z1 = Symbol("z1")
x1 = Poisson("x1", 3)
x2 = Poisson("x2", z1)
Ex2 = E(E(x2).subs(z1, x1))
Vx2 = E(E((x2-Ex2)**2).subs(z1, x1))
cov = E(E((z1-E(x1))*(x2-Ex2)).subs(z1, x1))
print("E(x2) = {}, var(x2) = {}, cov(x1, x2) = {}".format(Ex2, Vx2, cov))
```

Output:

```
E(x2) = 3, var(x2) = 6, cov(x1, x2) = 3
```

Notice the appearance of `Ex2` instead of `E(x2)` in the formulas for variance and covariance. Using `E(x2)` here would give  incorrect results because `E(x2)` is an expression involving z1. For the same reason I'm not using `variance` or `covariance` functions (as they'd involve the variable `E(x2)` instead of the correct value 3), expressing everything explicitly as an expected value.