# Sympy: Creating a Binomial random variable with Poisson number of trials

Tags: python, sympy

I have a random variable Y whose distribution is `Binomial(n,0.5)` where the number of trials `n` is itself a random variable `n~Poisson(10)`.

How can I use SymPy to automatically calculate the covariance between X and Y? 
The code

```
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.stats import Poisson, E, Binomial
z1 = Symbol("z1")
x1 = Poisson("x1", 10)
x2 = Binomial("x2", z1, 0.5)
Ex2 = E(E(x2).subs(z1, x1))
Vx2 = E(E((x2-Ex2)**2).subs(z1, x1))
cov = E(E((z1-E(x1))*(x2-Ex2)).subs(z1, x1))
print(cov)
```

raises an error
`TypeError: can't convert symbols to int`, due to the restriction on the trials argument of the Binomial constructor to be an integer, and not a symbol `z1`.

Suggesting a replacement of SymPy for this in python is also helpful.

This is a variant of [this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45237209/3025556).